# How to actually download the image from the image(url) formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the =IMAGE(URL) formula in google sheets.
The images are loaded from the url and then displayed in the cells.
I want to stop using the url to fetch images, and instead "download" them to display them.
So if the url changes it remains active.

How can I do that ? :)
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "download"? If you are trying to actual perform a download I'm afraid that there is no formula that could do that for you, the same will happen by using apps script, you will need to store the image somewhere so formulas and scripts won't be able to achieve an actual download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are just a couple of images, copy the URL from each `image()` formula and use **Insert > Image > Image in cell > By URL** to replace the formula with the image.

To automate that, you will need a script. Try something like this:

```js
function test() {
  const sheetRegex = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  let numRangesModified = 0;
  let totalNumReplaced = 0;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  try {
    ss.toast(`Replacing image formulas with in-cell images...`, 'Please wait', 30);
    const sheets = ss.getSheets()
      .filter(sheet => sheet.getName().match(sheetRegex));
    if (!sheets.length) {
      ss.toast(`Cannot find any sheets that match ${sheetRegex.toString()}.`);
      return;
    }
    const ranges = sheets.map(sheet => sheet.getDataRange());
    ranges.forEach(range => {
      const numReplaced = replaceImageFormulasWithImages_(range);
      if (numReplaced) {
        numRangesModified += 1;
        totalNumReplaced += numReplaced;
      }
    });
    ss.toast(`Replaced ${totalNumReplaced} image formula(s) with in-cell images in ${numRangesModified} range(s).`, 'Done', 10);
  } catch (error) {
    ss.toast(`Replaced ${totalNumReplaced} image formula(s) in ${numRangesModified} range(s). ${error.message}`, 'Error', 30);
  }
}

/**
* Replaces all image() formulas in a range with in-cell images.
*
* Supports formulas like image(E2) where E2 contains a URL, and
* formulas like image("https://www.example.com/pict/image01.png").
* The replacement is done cell by cell to work around an issue
* in the SpreadsheetApp API.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} range The range where to replace image() formulas with in-cell images.
* @return {Number} The number of image() formulas replaced with in-cell images.
*/
function replaceImageFormulasWithImages_(range) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 9 December 2022
  //  - add cellA1
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 8 December 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736461/13045193
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  let numReplaced = 0;
  range.getFormulas().forEach((row, rowIndex) =>
    row.forEach((formula, columnIndex) => {
      if (formula.match(/^(=image)/i)) {
        let url;
        let match = formula.match(/^=image\("(http[^"]+)"/i);
        if (match) {
          url = match[1];
        } else {
          match = formula.match(/^=image\(([A-Z]{1,3}\d{1,6})\)/i);
          if (match) {
            let cellA1 = match[1];
            try {
              url = sheet.getRange(cellA1).getDisplayValue();
            } catch (error) {
              ;
            }
          }
        }
        if (url) {
          range.offset(rowIndex, columnIndex, 1, 1).setValue(
            SpreadsheetApp
              .newCellImage()
              .setSourceUrl(url)
              .build()
          );
          numReplaced += 1;
        }
      }
    })
  );
  return numReplaced;
}
```

Replace `/^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i` with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) that matches the sheet names where you want to replace `image()` formulas with in-cell images. To replace on all sheets, use `/./i`.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks - the script looks good.

But I don't know why, I always have the message "Replaced 0 image formula(s) with in-cell images in 1 range(s)." displayed.

Is it possible for you to give me more details on how to actually use this script on a Sheets ? Thinks it will help others as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet where the issue can be reproduced. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: I just did it. Please find the sample data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOY5IrLtWuoCkeut7fE_kc96uztxhqivqXR6n4SjjHg/edit?usp=sharing.

Can't wait for your additional instructions. Thanks.

Comment: The `image()` formulas in your sample spreadsheet differ from what you stated. The code I gave you expects the format `=image(url)` where `url` is a URL. Your formulas are of the format `=image(cellRef)` where `cellRef` is like `E2`. You can test the code with this formula: `=image("https://scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/117800343_353199039016365_7322281613781737894_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=Ymjbanc3e5sAX-Bo2k3&edm=APQMUHMBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCDEC6BEetiJBJ6p4ynrUDkZSibx91SgB6JdV81xAgXDA&oe=63969675&_nc_sid=e5d0a6")`.

Comment: Edited the answer to add support for formulas like `=image(E2)`.